# Why does this class not compile?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

This code doesn't compile and I'm wondering is it because there is no constructor (like super constructor or anything) in `Puppy` or is it because of something else?

```
class Pet {
    String name;
    Pet(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class Puppy extends Pet {}

public class fiddle {

    public static void main(String[] args ){
        Pet pup = new Puppy("Doggo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what's the error message? That should give you a hint about what's wrong.

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly what the issue is. Read the output.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

> A subclass inherits all the members (fields, methods, and nested
>   classes) from its superclass. Constructors are not members, so they
>   are not inherited by subclasses, but the constructor of the superclass
>   can be invoked from the subclass.

You can change it to:

```
class Puppy extends Pet {
    public Puppy(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was suspecting I was just not sure. So thank you so much kind sir.

Comment: @GergelyOsbáth Glad to help. Please mark this answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

a `constructor` call on `Puppy` 's first task will be to call the `constructor` of the `parent class`.

If the `parent class` only had a `default (no parameter) constructor`, this would not pose a problem. If you add a `default constructor` to the `parent class`, again, no problem, but since there is no such `constructor` in the `parent class`, you need to tell your `child class` what to do.

So, you'll need to add a `constructor` to your `child class`, which calls the `constructor` of the `parent class`.

This can be:

```
public Puppy(String input) {
  super(input);
}
```

or

```
public Puppy() {
  super("default"); // or null, if you prefer that
}
```

but it needs to call an existing `constructor` of the `parent class` as first statement.

Comment: `why` did you add `random` code formatting `around` every other `word`? It makes it `really difficult` to read.

Comment: edit it if you will. I added them around the crucial parts the OP shouldn't look lover.

Comment: @Stultuske: that's usually what *italic* or **bold** text is for. Code formatting should be used for class names like `Puppy` or similar things only. Otherwise it'll get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Puppy` extends `Pet`. `Pet` has a custom constructor so, `Puppy` needs one as well like `public Puppy(String name){...}`

Answer (score 0):

You already provided the answer. Since `Puppy` is not abstract, it must be instantiate-able. The compiler is complaining because it has no way to do so. To construct an object `Puppy` you need also to call at least one of its supper class constructors. Now the only one constructor taking a parameter, a default no-arg constructor cannot be assumed. That's why you need to provide it yourself.

Something like:

```
public Puppy(String name) {
   super(name);
}
```

or:

```
public Puppy() {
   super("puppy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class, you still need to call it's constructor so that you can initialise the class and its fields. `Pet`'s constructor takes a String. By default, when you extend a class (as `Puppy` does) the compiler adds an *implicit call* to the no-argument constructor as a convenience. Because `Pet` does not have a no-argument constructor, this code does not compile.

You can fix it by calling the constructor which takes a string explicitly:

```
class Puppy extends Pet {
    Puppy(String name) {
        super("Puppy called " + name);
    }
}
```

or

```
class Puppy extends Pet {
    Puppy() {
        super("Puppy");
    }
}
```

Similarly (though you presumably don't want to do this), your code would compile if you removed the constructor from `Pet` because everything would be happening implicitly:

```
class Pet {
}
class Puppy extends Pet {
}
```

Internally, the compiler is turning this into:

```
class Pet {
    Pet() {
        // do nothing
    }
}
class Puppy extends Pet {
    Puppy() {
        super(); // call Pet's constructor
    }
}
```